# overriding redirect_to behavior with devise update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I thought would be a simple problem is giving me some trouble. I have an application with Devise/Omniauth for authentication. When a new user signs up and logs in, I want them to be directed to a couple of questions (in succession) asking:

1. what beverages do they like? (coffee, drink, both)
2. what neighborhoods are convenient for them?

My user model has a "preferred_beverage" attribute along with three preferred_neighborhood_# attributes (preferred_neighborhood_one, preferred_neighborhood_two, preferred_neighborhood_three).

When a user signs in, I want to check if they are a new user and if so, direct them to a page with question 1:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h2>What do you like to drink?</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :preferred_beverage, 'Coffee', :checked => true %> 
    <%= label :preferred_beverage, 'Coffee' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :preferred_beverage, 'Drink' %> 
    <%= label :preferred_beverage, 'Drink' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :preferred_beverage, 'Both' %> 
    <%= label :preferred_beverage, 'Both' %>

    <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem is that, upon submitting this form, even though the user's "preferred_beverage" attribute is saving, I cannot properly overwrite the default Devise "update" method, which seems to be handling any modifications to User and redirecting to the root_path. I want to redirect straight to my /app/views/neighborhood_survey/new.html.erb form upon submission of the 'preferred_beverage'.

What exactly do I need to put in the "update" section of this registrations_controller.rb that I am using to override the default Devise registrations_controller?

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  def update
  end

  private
  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

I completed the below to ensure that my registrations_controller was overwriting the Devise registrations controller with the following:

```
routes.rb

    devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
                       controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations"}
```

Any input is appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be overriding devise update action, you need to be overriding the

```
after_sign_in_path_for
```

route of devise. You will be able to redirect the user wherever you like after he signs in. You should put this in your application controller.

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method

Comment: thanks Kyle. it's not just the moment after sign in that's important though. it's after a redirect to the form for filling in a beverage. after that beverage is submitted, the user is updated and there should be another redirect to the page displaying the 2nd question (neighborhood). any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: I would make these questions a separate table so you do not have to worry about devise. What happened when you put super in the update action?